# Google Play Services R$string doesn't get imported

Tags: android, google-play-services

We are building the project completely from command line. Google Play Services library project is imported:

```
android.library.reference.1=path/to/google-play-services_lib
```

All GMS features that don't require resource files from GMS work fine (e.g. LocationClient). When I'm trying to prompt user to update GMS the following error occurs:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 3599): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string
E/AndroidRuntime( 3599):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.b(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3599):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.a(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3599):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(Unknown Source)
```

Undexing final classes.dex indicates that all strings are there:

```
user@host:~/path/to/project$ dexdump -d bin/classes.dex | grep com.google.android.gms.R
0991bc: 6000 e505                              |001a: sget v0, Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;.auth_client_play_services_err_notification_msg:I // field@05e5
09920c: 6004 e605                              |0042: sget v4, Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;.auth_client_requested_by_msg:I // field@05e6
099222: 6004 e405                              |004d: sget v4, Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;.auth_client_availability_notification_title:I // field@05e4
099b9e: 6000 ed05                              |0041: sget v0, Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;.common_google_play_services_install_title:I // field@05ed
099bb4: 6000 e905                              |004c: sget v0, Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;.common_google_play_services_enable_title:I // field@05e9
099bca: 6000 f305                              |0057: sget v0, Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;.common_google_play_services_update_title:I // field@05f3
099bee: 6000 f005                              |0069: sget v0, Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;.common_google_play_services_unsupported_title:I // field@05f0
099d2e: 6000 ea05                              |0009: sget v0, Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;.common_google_play_services_install_button:I // field@05ea
099d3c: 6000 e705                              |0010: sget v0, Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;.common_google_play_services_enable_button:I // field@05e7
099d4a: 6000 f105                              |0017: sget v0, Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;.common_google_play_services_update_button:I // field@05f1
099fc8: 6000 ee05                              |0004: sget v0, Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;.common_google_play_services_unknown_issue:I // field@05ee
099ff0: 6000 ec05                              |0018: sget v0, Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;.common_google_play_services_install_text_tablet:I // field@05ec
09a030: 6000 eb05                              |0038: sget v0, Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;.common_google_play_services_install_text_phone:I // field@05eb
09a03e: 6000 e805                              |003f: sget v0, Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;.common_google_play_services_enable_text:I // field@05e8
09a04c: 6000 f205                              |0046: sget v0, Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;.common_google_play_services_update_text:I // field@05f2
09a08c: 6000 ef05                              |0066: sget v0, Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;.common_google_play_services_unsupported_text:I // field@05ef
09c394: 6000 e205                              |001c: sget v0, Lcom/google/android/gms/R$drawable;.common_signin_btn_text_dark:I // field@05e2
09c398: 6001 e305                              |001e: sget v1, Lcom/google/android/gms/R$drawable;.common_signin_btn_text_light:I // field@05e3
09c3ba: 6000 e005                              |002f: sget v0, Lcom/google/android/gms/R$drawable;.common_signin_btn_icon_dark:I // field@05e0
09c3be: 6001 e105                              |0031: sget v1, Lcom/google/android/gms/R$drawable;.common_signin_btn_icon_light:I // field@05e1
09c454: 6000 de05                              |0000: sget v0, Lcom/google/android/gms/R$color;.common_signin_btn_text_dark:I // field@05de
09c458: 6001 df05                              |0002: sget v1, Lcom/google/android/gms/R$color;.common_signin_btn_text_light:I // field@05df
09c4aa: 6000 f405                              |002b: sget v0, Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;.common_signin_button_text:I // field@05f4
09c4be: 6000 f505                              |0035: sget v0, Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;.common_signin_button_text_long:I // field@05f5
0f2e38: 6201 f605                              |000e: sget-object v1, Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;.MapAttrs:[I // field@05f6
0f865e: 6202 f605                              |000d: sget-object v2, Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;.MapAttrs:[I // field@05f6
```

Any ideas on why I'm getting that error, and how to fix it?

Comment: have you reffered to the library project properly?

Comment: can you explain how you did this  *Google Play Services library project is imported*. you don't import you have to refer it in your android project

Comment: added the following in build.xml:
<property name="android.library.reference.1" value="path/to/google-play-services_lib">